# passing property from master page to aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, master-pages

I have a property in masterpage which i populate in page render event as below:

```
public string myproperty{get; set;}
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    myproperty = "TEST";          
}
```

on my aspx page I have a `<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>` and on page init event I access it as so:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    Site msPage = (Site)Page.Master;
    string t = msPage.myproperty ;
}
```

I can see the property on masterpage having a value but on aspx page it is always null. am I doing something wrong can someone help please.

Comment: You have forgotten to show us exactly how this value is placed onto the aspx page

Comment: @freefaller what you mean placed on aspx page? I thought if you assign a value to property in masterpage you would be able to get it in aspx page

Comment: it can't be set using OnInit Method..Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd6at422.aspx

Comment: Apologies @Sam1, I misunderstood... when you said "on aspx page" I thought you were referring to the displaying of the value within the HTML markup.

Comment: @Usman which event is suitable then?

Comment: @Sam1.. Page_Load method would be preferable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend you to read this:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.be/2007/10/right-way-of-accessing-master-page.html

Comment: I have read this before the only issue i am having is that the value is null and throws object reference not set exception

Comment: You are calling the property from the init method. Try to read the article again.

Answer (score 0):

The property isn't initialised yet.

The master page is actually implemented as a control in the page, so the page is initialised before the master page.